# Android Image not rotating after the 1st run using ViewPropertyAnimator

Tags: android, android-activity, android-animation, android-imageview

- I have two **ImageView(s)** set in my layout one on top of the other, say A and B.
- I have set the alpha of B to 0 so it's totally faded as I want to control which image is displayed by setting the appropriate alpha to 1 in my code.
- Now I also want to rotate the Images by 360 degrees before they fade out and before the new image comes on the screen when I click on the **ImageView(s)**.
- I'm using the **ViewPropertyAnimator's** `rotation()` and `alpha()` methods to do this.
- This works without any issues when the App is installed and runs for for 1st time.
- However, next time when I click on the Images, only the fade-in and fade-out animations work.
- The rotation does not work.
- Check this code :

  ```
  boolean isImage1Showing = true;

  //onClick() method for the 2 ImageView(s)
  public void fadeAndRotate(View view){         

  if (isImage1Showing){

      //Rotate the resource on 1st ImageView by 360 degrees
      imageViewA.animate().rotation(360f).setDuration(2000);

      imageViewA.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);

      //Displaying the other image on to the screen
      imageViewB.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);

      isImage1Showing = false;

      } else {
      isImage1Showing = true;

      imageViewB.animate().rotation(360f).setDuration(2000);

      //Displaying the previous image 
      imageViewA.animate().alpha(1).setDuration(2000);

      //fading out the currently displayed image
      imageViewB.animate().alpha(0).setDuration(2000);
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
.rotationBy(float value)
```

method instead of the

```
.rotation(float value)
```

method. In your case it rotates ***TO*** 360f but you want it to rotate ***BY*** 360f.

So this code should work :

```
imageViewA.animate().rotationBy(360f).setDuration(2000);
```